# Filters For Charts on Apex

Tags: oracle, charts, oracle-apex

I have figured out how to add a filter to my chart, is there a way that if I leave this filter null that it will display all data as opposed to no data?

This is the line I used to create the filter:

Paint_shop = :P9_Select_Shop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
where (Paint_shop = :P9_Select_Shop or :P9_Select_Shop is null)
```

Comment: What should I do if I want to add multiple filters? Thanks

Comment: Add them to WHERE clause, e.g. `where (paint_shop = :p9_select_shop or :p9_select_shop is null) AND (type = :p9_type or :p9_type is null) AND ...`

Comment: I tried that and for some reason the filter works but the first filter must be changed for the second one to work [ex: I put where (Paint_shop = :P9_Select_Shop or :P9_Select_Shop is null) AND (MODEL = :P9_Model or :P9_Model is null) ]    Is there some type of AND OR statement I could use?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what that means ("the first filter must be changed for the second one to work"). Are they *cascading* (e.g. you first select continents, and then list of countries contains only those that are located on previously selected continent)? If so, there's the "parent item(s)" property; for P9_MODEL, you'd put P9_SELECT_SHOP into it.

Comment: sORRY TO BOTHER YOU i FIGURED IT OUT. iT WAS A SMALL SETTING i HAD